# Extracting values from a cell in a table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm super new to Python and everything and I'm trying to get BeautifulSoup to return a number value from one specific cell from this one table from this page
(or any other similar page in the same wiki)

For now all that I have is:

```
url = ('http://unisonleague.wikia.com/wiki/Brynhildr,_Dual_Lancer_(Gear)')
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup (data , 'html.parser')
table = soup.find (id='mw-content-text')
rows = table.find ('tr')
cells = rows.findAll('td')
```

The value that I want is from the cell next to "Max Unison Chance", so "10004" in this case.

```
<td colspan="2" style="background-color:#5B4F3D; color:#ffffff;"> 10004 </td>
```

I tried

```
 soup.findAll('td colspan="2"')
```

and

```
soup.find('td colspan')
```

but it just returned nothing or an empty list.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here, I thought about/tried indexing by number of rows (I believe this is row [14]) and maybe the cell but I couldn't seem to get the code right?

Comment: Better use xpath

Comment: Try to make your example (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve], i.e it should run stand-alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a top down approach like you are doing use the tree structure of the html to your advantage. I assume you wanted to generalize this to other similarly formatted pages so what you can do is you can treat the cell with "Max Unison Chance" in it as an anchor point where you will then traverse the parse tree that Beautiful Soup creates to get to the cell that you're looking for. Here is the html that contains both the description cell and the cell you're looking for/

```
<td style="height: 29px; background-color:#3F2D18; color:#ffffff; font-size:7pt;"> <b><span style="cursor:help;" title="Maximum stats used during a Unison Chance. It is the total of both stats with +198.">Max Unison Chance</span>:</b>
</td><td colspan="2" style="background-color:#5B4F3D; color:#ffffff;"> 10004
</td>
```

Here you can directly get the html tag that contains "Max Unison Chance" by calling:

```
element = soup.find(text='Max Unison Chance')
```

This will get you the element that has the text "Max Unison Chance" in it.
If you then look at where the tag that contains the number that you are looking for is relative to the element that you now have. You can see that you need to go up three nodes to get to the element that is next to the cell with 10004 in it.

To navigate to this cell we can use the parent attribute of the element we have and use attribute chaining:

`great_grandparent = element.parent.parent.parent`

We now need to get the next_sibling of our great_grandparent by:

```
target_cell = great_grandparent.next_sibling
```

And lastly grabbing the element's text value and cleaning it up:

```
result = target_cell.text.strip()
```

Then putting it all together:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = ('http://unisonleague.wikia.com/wiki/Brynhildr,_Dual_Lancer_(Gear)')
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup (data , 'html.parser')
element= soup.find(text='Max Unison Chance')
result = element.parent.parent.parent.next_sibling.text.strip()
```

An alternative way to do this is do use the parse order instead of the tree order so you could replace result with:

```
result = cell.next.next.next.strip()
```

Since the next attribute refers to the next element based on how the parser that you are using works

Comment: `result = element.find_next('td').text` would also work well here, I think.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer! It works really well and I actually understand everything.